# Expected end of statement error while i am trying to sum values of a dynamically increasing column

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Range(Str_rng &"2"&":"& Str_rng & finalOlastRow-1)"
```

In the above code Str_rng gives column address and value from 2 nd row to last row -1 have to be added in the last row . However it is throwing Expected end of statement error.

Comment: Try this instead: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & Str_rng & "2" & ":" & Str_rng & finalOlastRow - 1 & ")"`.

Comment: Thanks , it worked !

Comment: I realised that . Your proposed formula worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct line of code should be:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & Str_rng & "2:" & Str_rng & finalOlastRow - 1 & ")"
```

Just to demystify the solution here is why:

[image]

The yellow parts (between the quotations) will be entered into the formula as is (no changes). The green portions must be letters to indicate the columns. The blue portion must be a number to indicate the ending row (for the sum). Also, it must be a number because it is used in a calculation (from which 1 is deducted).

So, assuming that `Str_rng = "E"` and that `finalOlastRow = 21` the above formula converts to:

```
"=SUM(" & "E" & "2:" & "E" & 20 & ")"
```

which is equal to

```
"=SUM(E2:E20)"
```

Note, that the number 20 is not a string (text). Yet, VBA automatically detects that you want to add a number to a text and converts the number to text (to make the concatenation possible).

Comment: ActiveCell.Formula = "=G2 +H2 +K2 +I2 + " & Last_Str_rng & "2""" . this is giving me an error . What could be the reason ?

Comment: When in doubt just change the line to `MsgBox = "=G2 +H2 +K2 +I2 + " & Last_Str_rng & "2"""`. Then you get to see the resulting formula in a new message box. There you'll see the error yourself immediately. You'll note that there is one too many characters at the end.

Comment: Just so you know: we (here at this site) strive to teach each others so we learn. We don't like to provide yet another working solutions. We prefer to give all the help we can for you to find the solution yourself. Otherwise, you keep coming for the same problem / reason.

Comment: Nice approach to explain. Appreciated.