# Introduce variables in recorded VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded part of this macro in Excel:

```
    Cells(x, i).Select
        Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=SQRT((MMULT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(R2C14:R9C14),'Monthly Covariance y1'!R[12]C[0]:R[19]C[7]),'Portfolio Vola per Month'!R2C14:R9C14)))"
```

In the middle term " 'Monthly Covariance y1'!R[12]C[**0**]:R[19]C[**7**])" I want to express the bold numbers as variables. **0** should be **j** and **7** should be **j+7**.

When I try to replace the hard numbers by variables, Excel returns "Unable to set FormulaArray property of the Range class".

Any idea on how I can work around this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just close the formula, add variables, and open again:

`"=SQRT((MMULT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(R2C14:R9C14),'Monthly Covariance y1'!R[12]C["& j & "]:R[19]C["& j + 7 & "]),'Portfolio Vola per Month'!R2C14:R9C14)))"`

By "close the formula", I mean close with a `"`, then use `&` to connect the variables, then "reopen" with `"`.  Simple example, with `j` being a row number, say `5`:

`myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(A" & j & ":A" & j & ")"`

is equivalent to

`myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(A5:A5)"`

Also, this is another issue altogether, but try to [avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: I once made a visual representation of "closing a formula" (as Bruce refers to it) in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040259/expected-end-of-statement-error-while-i-am-trying-to-sum-values-of-a-dynamically/38040342#38040342 Hope that helps understanding.

Comment: @Ralph - Oh, nice! I'll have to keep that URL for the future, cheers!